# is $i$ units east equivalent to 1 unit north?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

this question is certainly strange but i can't stop thinking about it. if $i$ is 90 degrees away from 1 on the complex plane, is $i$ units east equal to one unit north? would appreciate anything y'all think about this.

Comment: In what context? I think I have seen this analogy used in order to help visualize the complex plane, but I do not thing I have ever seen anyone give directions or attempt to navigate using complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an unreasonable thing to say, although it's not usual to speak of cardinal directions on the complex plane.

For an analogy that doesn't use complex numbers, you probably wouldn't say that Annapolis, MD is about -50 miles West of DC as this is much more confusing than just using positive numbers; however, this is a perfectly consistent way to talk about direction on a one dimensional highway in the sense that it won't run into any contradictions.

Comment: thank you!!!!!!